# Two-way DataGrid binding with record structure (dynamic columns and rows)

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, xname

I have a record structure that I am trying to bind to a `DataGrid`. Basically, my columns are dynamically specified by the view model. The value that should be displayed (and edited) in grid cell must be retrieved using a function on each record (the view model behind each row of the grid).

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171098/binding-datagrid-to-observablecollectiondictionary) and it got me half the way there. Unfortunately, I cannot use a `DynamicObject` because my properties on the record are namespaced names and as such cannot be represented by a string. I tried a variation where I converted this namespaced name into a bindable string (replacing all illegal characters with an underscore) but it seems like the `DynamicObject` would call `TryGetMember` every time I navigated the `DataGrid` (i.e. it would call the function for every cell every time I scrolled). That performance is not going to be good enough.

This is what I have so far that works for displaying data (i.e. `GetValue`):

```
public interface IDataSet
{
    IEnumerable<IRecord> Records { get; }
    IEnumerable<IProperty> PropertiesToDisplay { get; } 
}

public interface IProperty
{
    XName Name { get; }
}

public interface IRecord
{
    IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<IProperty, object>> Values { get; set; }

    object GetValue(IProperty property);
    void SetValue(IProperty property, object value);
}

internal class SomeClass
{
    DataGrid myGrid;    // this is defined in the XAML
    IDataSet viewModel; // this is the DataContext

    private void BindToViewModelUsingConverter()
    {
        foreach (IProperty property in viewModel.PropertiesToDisplay)
        {
            Binding binding = new Binding();
            binding.Converter = new ConvertMyDataConverter();
            binding.ConverterParameter = property;

            var column = new DataGridTextColumn
            {
                Header = property.Name.LocalName,
                Binding = binding
            };

            myGrid.Columns.Add(column);
        }

        myGrid.ItemsSource = viewModel.Records;
    }
}

internal class ConvertMyDataConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var record = value as IRecord;
        var property = parameter as IProperty;

        if (record != null && property != null)
        {
            return record.GetValue(property);
        }

        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // not sure what to do here, yet
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The above code works when it comes to showing values. However, as soon as I try to edit values I get an exception:

```
**Two-way binding requires Path or XPath**
```

This makes sense because even in my converter above, I'm not sure what I would write in the `ConvertBack` function since I want the source to remain the same (since I'm binding to `IRecord` and have already called the `IRecord.SetValue` function to update the data.) However, it seems like `ConvertBack` would not give me a reference to `IRecord` even if I was able to do two-way binding without a path.

Is there something trivial that I am missing? I'm not averse to developing a custom control but would like some tips/ideas on how to approach the problem.

Comment: "That performance is not going to be good enough."  - try it first.

Comment: @Henk: I did try it and it was horrible. "(i.e. it would call the function for every cell every time I scrolled)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using `ICustomTypeDescriptor` and `ITypedList`. Instead of `Records` being an `IEnumerable<IRecord>`, I made it a custom collection that implemented `IList<IRecord>` as well as `ITypedList`. For the `ITypedList` implementation, I returned property descriptors that wrapped my `IProperty` implementation:

```
public interface IDataSet
{
    TypedRecordsCollection Records { get; }
    IEnumerable<IProperty> PropertiesToDisplay { get; } 
}

public class TypedRecordsCollection : ObservableCollection<RecordViewModel>, ITypedList
{
    private PropertyDescriptorCollection _properties;

    public TypedRecordsCollection(IEnumerable<IRecord> records)
    {
        _properties = new PropertyDescriptorCollection(
            PropertiesToDisplay
                .Select(prop => new CustomPropertyDescriptor(prop))
                .ToArray());
        records.ForEach(rec => Items.Add(new RecordViewModel(rec, _properties)));
    }

    public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetItemProperties(PropertyDescriptor[] listAccessors)
    {
        return _properties;
    }
 }   

 public interface IRecordViewModel : ICustomTypeDescriptor
 {
    object GetCellValue(IProperty property);
    void SetCellValue(IProperty property, object value);
 }

 public class RecordViewModel : CustomTypeDescriptor, IRecord
 {
    private IRecord _record;
    private PropertyDescriptorCollection _properties;

    public RecordViewModel(IRecord record, PropertyDescriptorCollection properties)
    {
        _record = record;
        _properties = properties;
    }

    public object GetCellValue(IProperty property)
    {
        return _record.GetValue(property);
    }

    public void SetCellValue(IProperty property, object value)
    {
        _record.SetValue(property, value);
    }

    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties()
    {
        return _properties;
    }
 }

 public class CustomPropertyDescriptor : PropertyDescriptor
 {
    private IProperty _property;

    public CustomPropertyDescriptor(IProperty property)
        : base(GetCleanName(property.Name), new Attribute[0])
    {
        _property = property;
    }

    public override object GetValue(object component)
    {
        var recordViewModel = component as IRecordViewModel;
        if (recordViewModel != null)
        {
            return recordViewModel.GetCellValue(_property);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public override void SetValue(object component, object value)
    {
        var recordViewModel = component as IRecordViewModel;
        if (recordViewModel != null)
        {
            recordViewModel.SetCellValue(_property, value);
        }
    }

    private static string GetCleanName(XName name)
    {
        // need to return a XAML bindable string.. aka no "{}" or ".", etc.
    }
 }
```

Now in my XAML I can just set `AutogenerateColumns` to true and bind directly to the `Records` property without a converter.